# Can't launch CoverGloobus: ImportError

Tags: 10.10, python, covergloobus

I installed CoverGloobus on my ubuntu 10.10. But every time I try to run it, I get this error:

```
[WARNING] Using default configuration
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "covergloobus-config.py", line 32, in <module>
    Configuration.run()
  File "/usr/share/covergloobus/widgets/configuration.py", line 94, in run
    Configuration.__instance = Configuration(cg)
  File "/usr/share/covergloobus/widgets/configuration.py", line 155, in __init__
    self.make_pages()
  File "/usr/share/covergloobus/widgets/configuration.py", line 165, in make_pages
    page = method()
  File "/usr/share/covergloobus/widgets/configuration.py", line 432, in make_lyrics
    for klass in GenericLyric.load():
  File "/usr/share/covergloobus/lyrics/__init__.py", line 34, in load
    __import__('lyrics.' + name[:-3])
  File "/usr/share/covergloobus/lyrics/lyricswikia.py", line 26, in <module>
    from lyrics import GenericLyric
ImportError: cannot import name GenericLyric
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: It seems like some Python module it tries to use is missing.  How and from where did you install this?

Comment: I installed it using the .deb file on this page:
https://launchpad.net/~gloobus-dev/+archive/covergloobus/+packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a python package race condition, the class does exist (note: JanC, it's not always because the module is missing) you can see GenericLyric in `lyrics/__init__.py` but it's while it's importing init that it tried to import init. Bad race condition.

The fix is to get a programmer involved, to do that you should report the bug here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/covergloobus

See also this guide:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs